# Second order DE problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve :

> $$x(x-1)y''-(2x-1)y'+2y=x^2(2x-3)$$

I have tried solving the DE by using the following three methods:

1. Solution in terms of part of CF (was unable to find a standard CF)
2. Normal form ($R_1$ and $Q_1$ look very complex)
3. Change of independent variable ($Q_1$ is very complex)

The question seems simple but I have not been able to determine a solution. I appreciate any ideas on how to solve the DE.

Thanks

Comment: The dsolve command of Maple produces $$y \left( x \right) ={x}^{2}{C_2}+ \left( -2\,x+1 \right) {C_1}+{x}^{3}.$$

Comment: Sorry but the motivation given for the bounty and the bounty itself are rather bizarre. "The one answer already given doesn't do it by one of the standard methods for solving such DE" is plain wrong and "I have worked a lot on this problem and could not fighue out what to do" has a simple answer: read and digest the answer already posted.

Comment: @Did : Thanks !! I'll keep looking for what i want

Comment: @Did I think that for an undergrad student, who is learning ODE, zuggg's idea in his answer is very hard to follow.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Thanks for your input. You seem pretty confident that your answer would be easier to follow. Why is that so?

Comment: @Did Hi, I have been teaching ODE for several years, this is the presentation shown in Boyce and DiPrima, which is a very standard textbook for undergrad. It is a standardized procedure that doesn't require much math reasoning skills, just following substitution->characteristic equation->variation of parameters this kinda routine.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao The question is not whether the presentation you suggest is kosher or not, but what are its advantages when compared to zuggg's.

Comment: @Did Honestly I don't know, I think it depends on if OP could follow my presentation. If he could not, I'd say there is no advantage to zuggg's answer.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I completely agree with your last comment.

Answer (score 6):

First notice that for $t>0$
$$
y = c_1 t+ c_2 t^2\quad \text{solves}\quad t^2 y'' -2ty' + 2y=0.
$$
This can be done by letting $y = t^{r}$ and we can get the characteristic equation $(r-1)(r-2)t^r = 0$.

---

Now we want to reduce the homogeneous part of your equation
$$x(x-1)y''-(2x-1)y'+2y=0\tag{1}$$
to something like above. A reasonable guess is that since the derivative of a polynomial contains linear combination of its factors, we make substitution: 
$$
t = x-1,
$$
and (1) becomes:
$$
t(t+1)y'' -(2t+1)y' + 2y=0.
$$
Let $y = t^{r}$, then $y' = rt^{r-1}$ and $y'' = r(r-1)t^{r-2}$, plugging above equation yields
$$
(r-2)\Big[(r-1)t^r + rt^{r-1}\Big] = 0,
$$
so $r=2$ will make everthing vanish no matter what $t$, this gives us the first solution to (1): 
$$y_1 = t^2 = (x-1)^2.$$
Second solution to (1) can be found in a similar way:
$$y_2 = (2x-1).$$
We can check the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ does not vanish so they form a fundamental set of solutions for (1), and second order equation has only two elements in its fundamental set of solutions, we found all solution to (1):
$$
y_c = c_1 (x-1)^2 + c_2 (2x-1).\tag{2}
$$

---

Now we turn to the inhomogeneous equation
$$
x(x-1)y''-(2x-1)y'+2y=x^2(2x-3),\tag{3}
$$
so that we wanna find a particular solution for (3) that does not contain any terms in the homogeneous solution $y_c$ (for any terms being sent into the differential operator of left hand side will just vanish). The standard way of doing this is by **Variations of Parameters**: let
$$
y = u_1(x)(x-1)^2 + u_2(x)(2x-1).\tag{$\star$}
$$
This implies
$$
y' = u_1'(x-1)^2 + 2u_1(x-1) + u_2'(2x-1) + 2u_2.
$$
Setting 
$$
u_1'(x-1)^2 + u_2'(2x-1) = 0\tag{4}
$$
we get the first equation that is needed to get $u_1$ and $u_2$. Now that 
$$
y' =   2u_1(x-1)  + 2u_2,
$$
taking derivative again 
$$
y'' = 2u_1'(x-1) + 2u_1 + 2u_2'.
$$
Plugging $y,y',y''$ into (3):
$$
2x(x-1)^2u_1' + 2x(x-1)u_1 + 2x(x-1)u_2'
\\
-2(2x-1)(x-1)u_1 - 2(2x-1)u_2 
\\
+ 2(x-1)^2u_1 + 2(2x-1)u_2 = x^2(2x-3).
$$
You will find most terms get canceled and what is left is the second equation:
$$
2x(x-1)^2u_1'  + 2x(x-1)u_2' = x^2(2x-3).\tag{5}
$$
Solving (4) and (5) gives:
$$\begin{aligned}u_1' &= \frac{(2x-1)(2x-3)}{2(x-1)^2}
\\
u_2' &= - \frac{2x-3}{2}\end{aligned} \implies 
\begin{aligned}u_1  &= 2 x + \frac{1}{2(x-1)} + c_1
\\
u_2  &= - \frac{x(x-3)}{2}+c_2\end{aligned} $$
Now back to equation $(\star)$:
$$
y = \underbrace{c_1 (x-1)^2 + c_2 (2x-1)}_{\text{solution for the homogeneous equation}} + \underbrace{x^3 - \frac12 x^2 +x -\frac12}_{\text{particular solution}}.
$$
This is the presentation I will give in an undergrad ODE class.

Answer (score 4):

Notice how the degree of the polynomial coefficients in your equation is equal to the order of differentiation of each term. That calls for a polynomial solution. Let $P(x)=ux^n+...$, with $u\not=0$. We want $P$ to be a solution of the DE. Since the right hand side of the equation is a polynomial of degree 3, we must have $\deg(P)=n\ge3$.

Next, let us look at the coefficient in front of the monomial of highest degree in
$$
    x(x-1)P''(x)-(2x-1)P'(x)+2P(x).
$$
It is equal to
$$
    n(n-1)u-2nu+2u=u(n(n-3)+2)\not=0
$$
because $n\geq3$.

$$
    x(x-1)P''(x)-(2x-1)P'(x)+2P(x)=x^2(2x-3)
$$
implies $n=3$ and $u=1$. Therefore, we are looking for solutions of the DE with the form $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$. Plugging this into the equation yields only one simple condition
$$
    b+2c=0,
$$
meaning that any polynomial with the form $P(x)=x^3+ax^2-2cx+c$ is a solution of the DE. Notice that this represents an affine space of dimension 2, which means it is the complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use power series to solve this DE, it is much easier. Since $x=0$ is a normal point of the DE, $y$ can be represented as a power series at $x=0$. Let 
$$ y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n. $$
Then
$$ y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}, y''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}. $$
So the DE becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2-x)\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-(2x-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=2x^3-3x^2
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty[(n+1)na_{n+1}+2 na_{n}]x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n+1)a_{n+1}+2a_n]x^n=2x^3-3x^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Comparing the coefficients of $x^n, n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$ in both sides respectively, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_1+2a_0=0,-3a_3=-3,a_3=a_4=\cdots=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the solution of the DE is
$$ y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3=a_0-2a_0x+a_2x^2+x^3=a_0(1-2x)+a_2x^2+x^3. $$

Comment: Are you certain of this?  How do you know there's no non-integral power or logarithm in the solution?

Comment: @RonGordon, this is because $x=0$ is a normal point of the DE and hence $y$ can be represented as a power series.

Comment: Right.  A mention of that in your solution would help.